# Convert xml payload to a string in dataweave 2.0

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, dataweave

How to convert xml payload to a string in dataweave 2.0?

Thanks
Vempati

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way would be something like.

```
output application/java
---
payload.^raw as String
```

The `.^raw` returns the underlying input stream then we transform it into a `String` and return it as a Java Value so the payload is a `java.lang.String`

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.1/dw-core-functions-write

```
write(payload, "text/plain", {"encoding": "UTF-8"})
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, Good to know about this function. But it is not working for XML to String.